# add Apostrophe character using sed

Tags: shell, sed, command

How do I add ' (Apostrophe) character using sed command in between a line. I used following command on mac computer. But it just add a space.

```
sed -i '' 's/cur i   s/cur i '' s/g' ./edit_char.cmd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this (see the double quotes) :

```
sed -i'' "s/cur i   s/cur i '' s/g" ./edit_char.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
sed -Ei '' 's/(cur i ) ( s)/\1'\''\2/g' ./edit_char.cmd
```